# Signed applet doesn't show publisher information

Tags: java, security, applet, code-signing

I signed my applet using `.pfx` file. But when I run my web page it shows "UNKNOWN publisher warning".

I also have another certificate `.cer` (How to check that its a code signing certificate)[I got it from another person and he is also not sure].

So to sign applet, do I need special certificate say "Code Signing" certificate? Or I'm missing something?

[image]

Comment: You very obviously have a self-signed certificate because the issuer and the subject are the same.

Answer (score 2):

A digital certificate that is generated by me or you will read `UNKNOWN` in that dialog.  The reason is that if you can make a certificate claiming that you are you, *I* can just as easily make a certificate claiming that ***I*** am ***you***.

In order to avoid lying to the end-user, Oracle just reports 'unknown' for those 'self signed' applications.

Get a code-signing certificate with a key-chain pointing back to a Certification Authority (who take steps to verify the identity claimed by the applicant - and overcharge to do it), and the dialog will show the author.

---

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502802/418556) to [Signing a jar file with trusted certificate for JWS deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19458676/418556) for the intricacies of showing the author.

[image]