# Signing a jar file with trusted certificate for JWS deployment

Tags: java, certificate, java-web-start, code-signing

I've developed an open source program, WPCleaner, which is distributed through Java Web Start.  Current version is available at http://site4145.mutu.sivit.org/WikiCleaner/WikiCleaner.jnlp

With the recent updates in Java, it becomes more and more difficult to deploy Java applications through Java Web Start when you need the application to have a few permissions (writing in the preferences, accessing other web sites, ...)

My application was self-signed, which was ok before but new updates require users to accept the application every time they run it, not just once and for all if they wish. So, I decided to use a trusted certificate for signing my application.

I got one from Certum (apparently, they're free for open source developers), following this discussion: [Code signing certificate for open-source projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177552/code-signing-certificate-for-open-source-projects)

I've generated a new jar file, signed with this certificate (jar file available at http://site4145.mutu.sivit.org/WikiCleaner/WikipediaCleanerTest.jar), but I still have problems: when I start the application through JWS, Java still displays a warning windows not letting me trust the application once and for all. Editor is still displayed as UNKNOWN, but when I look in the details of the message, it's my new certificate from Centrum that's being used.

Does anyone have an idea on what I'm doing wrong ?
I thought that having a certificate from a trusted CA (Centrum seems to be in Java cacerts) would allow users to accept the certificate once and for all.

Thanks

PS: When I run `jarsigner -verify`, I get the following warning
"This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I finally managed to do it following this procedure:

- Installed the certificate provided by Certum in Chrome through their web site interface
- Exported the private key as a .pfx from Chrome (Settings, Manage certificates, Export, Export the private key, PKCS#12, ...)
- Used KeyTool GUI (java fronted GUI for keytools) to create a complete p12: imported Certum root certificate as a trusted certificate, imported intermediate certificates as trusted certificates, imported my .pfx as a key pair
- Signed the jar with this p12

Seems to work for me, I'm waiting for other users feedback to be sure that it works for them also.

Edit: I tried again to export the certificate from Chrome, and I saw that there's an option to include the certificate chain in the export. When doing this, I don't even need to use the KeyTool GUI afterwards. I've redeployed the test version signed with this new p12 :

- Installed the certificate provided by Certum in Chrome through their web site interface
- Exported the private key as a .pfx from Chrome (Settings, Manage certificates, Export, Export the private key, PKCS#12 + include certificate chain, ...)
- Signed the jar with this p12

Comment: *"Exported the private key as a .pfx"*  Using the SDK keytool?  Could you go into more detail on the command(s) issued?

Comment: I changed the description to provide more details. And I saw that I can create a complete p12 directly from Chrome without the need for KeyTool GUI. I've redeployed this newly signed jar as the test version.

Comment: *"Exported the private key as a .pfx from Chrome (Settings, Manage certificates.."*  Huh?  I See no option like that in Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m..

Comment: Also Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m, under Win 7: in the Settings tab, I click first on "Show advanced settings" to display more settings. Then, in the "HTTP/SSL" part (between "Downloads" and "Google Cloud Print"), I have a "Manage certificates..." button. You don't have this ?

Answer (score 10):

**[Update 2017]** Open Source code signing from Certum now uses a cryptographic flash card as a Private Key and must be plugged-in for certificate activation & installation, as well as for code signature. The key costs 125$ (+ shipping fee) and the 1-year certificate alone costs 40$. You can ask for a discount.

---

Here are the following steps to sign your jar file from scratch.

**Instructions**

Instructions in English are hard to find and not up to date. The following procedure is based on these 2 documents:

- [Partial Instructions for Installation and Activation (English)](https://www.certum.eu/en/data/Instruction-of-activation-and-installation-of-Code-Signing-Certificate.pdf) - The part about file "bundle.pem" is missing.
- [Complete Instructions for Installation and Activation (Polish)](https://www.certum.pl/pl/data/Instrukcja-aktywacji-i-instalacji-Code-Signing-Pl-v.2.pdf)

**Create, activate and install your certificate:**

1. Go on the "Certum Certification" website in the ["OpenSource Code Signing" section](https://en.sklep.certum.pl/data-safety/code-signing-certificates/open-source-code-signing-930.html) and order your certificate.
2. Once the cryptographic flash card is received (it took 15 days for me), plug it, install the driver and the *proCertum CardManager* software from the card.
3. Go to your Certum account and follow the activation process of your newly ordered certificate.

> **Tip:** The CryptoAgent Java Web Start application runs only with a JDK (not JRE) < 9 (so, JDK 7 or 8).

4. You'll receive a mail asking for some official documents (ID card, rent bill, etc.) and an e-mail verification procedure.
5. Send the activation required documents and information. You'll receive another mail asking for installing the certificate (the verification was done within 1 hour).
6. Install the certificate on the cryptographic card following the procedure *Storing the Certificate on the card* (see the instructions in English, part 4)

**Obtain the file "bundle.pem"**

This file is mandatory for obtaining a valid certificate chain when signing your application (see the part 7.1.2 in the instructions in Polish).

Basically, it consists of concatenating in a plain text format file 1) your certificate and 2) the *Certum Code Signing CA SHA2* public key.

1. Open *proCertum CardManager* >> *Read Card* >> tab *Common* >> Select your certificate and click "Show details"
2. Export your certificate: x509 - base-64
3. Download the [Certum Code Signing CA SHA2](https://repository.certum.pl/cscasha2.pem) in PEM format (from the [list of root certificates](https://www.certum.eu/certum/cert,expertise_root_certificates.xml) of Certum).
4. Create the text file "bundle.pem" by concatenating these 2 certificates (first your certificate and second the Certum certificate).

**Sign your jar file with Jarsigner**

1. Create the "provider.cfg" file as explained in the point 7.2 of the instructions in English.
2. You need the **alias** of your certificate (and not the **owner name**) to sign your jar. To obtain it execute the following command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 -providerClass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 -providerArg "provider.cfg" -storepass "[your_pin]"
```

3. Once you got the *alias*, the *provider.cfg* and *bundle.pem* files ready, just sign your jar with the following command:

```
jarsigner -keystore NONE -certchain "bundle.pem" -tsa "http://time.certum.pl" -storetype PKCS11 -providerClass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 -providerArg "provider.cfg" -storepass "[your_pin]" "[your_code].jar" "[your_alias]"
```

Personally, I use an Ant script to sign my application jar files. See [signjar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html) from ANT project.

Comment: This was it, thank you! Getting the proper alias from the P12 was the missing piece for me. With this procedure I got my free open-source certificate from Certum working.

Comment: Please be sure to use the same Chrome for operations 1 to 5. Step 2 installs something inside Chrome (I think it is a public/private key pair) that is required at step 4 (and later). 
Trying to achieve step 4 (and later) not on the browser that was used for step 2 will fail with an error.

Comment: On Linux, Chrome is unable to include the certification chain when exporting a key. So step 6 will export an incomplete .pfx key. To obtain a complete key, you must get these two files from Certum: https://www.certum.eu/upload_module/downloads/certum/certyfikaty/nowe/l3.crt and https://www.certum.pl/CA.crt , open your incomplete .pfx key in KeyTool GUI, right click the key, choose "Edit Certificate Chain > Append Certificate" and add l3.crt, right click the key again, choose "Edit Certificate Chain > Append Certificate" and add CA.crt. Save and quit. And now your key is ready for step 7 and 8.

Comment: [JWS](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml): When client access [`JNLP`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) file. To download and run Java applications([Signed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html) & Certified) from the web. [`Configure untrusted`](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml) Java-App URL in `Exception Site List` as `https://hostname.example.com:8088` to run from WEB.  
[`Example`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/usingJNLPAPI.html)

Answer (score 3):

> I'm waiting for other users feedback to be sure that it works for them also.

Based on JaNeLA for the file - valid JNLP. Most importantly **known publisher** for [WikiCleanerTest](http://site4145.mutu.sivit.org/WikiCleaner/WikiCleanerTest.jnlp)..

[image]

So there is one result of 'seems to work here for identifying the publisher'.  Great work and thanks for description of the process.

Works so much better than the one I looked at before. :P

---

### Jarsigner -verify

```
s     292828 Sun Oct 20 17:57:58 EST 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
      292645 Sun Oct 20 17:57:58 EST 2013 META-INF/WPCLEANE.SF
        2017 Sun Oct 20 17:57:58 EST 2013 META-INF/WPCLEANE.RSA
           0 Sun Oct 20 17:57:52 EST 2013 META-INF/
           0 Wed Feb 11 15:04:50 EST 2009 META-INF/maven/
           ..
           0 Sun Oct 20 17:57:32 EST 2013 org/xnap/commons/i18n/
sm      2837 Thu Sep 09 16:00:54 EST 2004 META-INF/info.xml
..
sm       214 Wed Feb 11 00:57:02 EST 2009 org/xnap/commons/i18n/LocaleChangeListener.class

  s = signature was verified 
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.

Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.

Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.
```

I understand the warning:

> This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.

..can be ignored.

### JaNeLA Report

[JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) shows one error.

```
JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17

Report for http://site4145.mutu.sivit.org/WikiCleaner/WikiCleaner.jnlp

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'homepage'. One of '{description, icon, offline-allowed, shortcut, association, related-content}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'homepage'. One of '{description, icon, offline-allowed, shortcut, association, related-content}' is expected.

XML encoding not known, but declared as utf-8
Codebase + href 'http://site4145.mutu.sivit.org/WikiCleaner.jnlp' is not equal to actual location of 'http://site4145.mutu.sivit.org/WikiCleaner/WikiCleaner.jnlp'.
Desktop icons were subject to bug nnnn in earlier J2SE versions
Optimize this application for off-line use by adding the <offline-allowed /> flag.
'short' description is longer than 'default' description.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'WikipediaCleaner.jar'.
The resource download at WikipediaCleaner.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for WikipediaCleaner.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Resource type png of resource commons-nuvola-web-broom.png is not one of the allowable types of gif, jpg, jpeg.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'commons-nuvola-web-broom.png'.
Icon loading & use can be optimized by specifying the width and height for commons-nuvola-web-broom.png
```

See the JNLP validated, and a corrected version with tweak, below.

### Launch

But here is the real bad news:

[image: UNKNOWN publisher]
[image: UNKNOWN publisher - More Info.]

Here are some details of the certificate:

- Nicolas Vervelle (Nicolas Vervelle)

  - **Subject:** CN=Nicolas Vervelle,
    OU=WikipediaCleaner,
    O=WikipediaCleaner,
    L=Paris,
    ST=France,
    C=FR

#### Out Of Date Java

Here is a strange warning I do not understand..

[image: Out Of Date Java]

The app. is requesting 1.5.0+ so any version 1.7+ should be accepted without question.
It claims to be requesting 1.6 (probably because I have no 1.5 run-time installed). The only thing I can think is triggering the warning is the inclusion of a micro-version, which is unnecessary.

### JNLP

Here is the JNLP validated above:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.5+" codebase="http://site4145.mutu.sivit.org/WikiCleaner" href="WikiCleaner.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>WPCleaner</title>
    <vendor>User:NicoV</vendor>
    <description>WPCleaner</description>
    <description kind="short">A tool for Wikipedia maintenance</description>
    <homepage href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:WPCleaner"/>
    <icon href="commons-nuvola-web-broom.png"/>
    <shortcut>
      <desktop/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.5.0+" java-vm-args="-Xmx512M"/>
    <jar href="WikipediaCleaner.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="org.wikipediacleaner.WikipediaCleaner"/>
</jnlp>
```

Here is a suggested replacement.  It is valid according to JaNeLA (bar warnings that we can ignore).  It also includes another tweak to the minimum version attribute.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.5+" codebase="http://site4145.mutu.sivit.org/WikiCleaner" href="WikiCleaner.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>WPCleaner</title>
    <vendor>User:NicoV</vendor>
    <!-- Should be here.. -->
    <homepage href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:WPCleaner"/>
    <description>WPCleaner</description>
    <description kind="short">A tool for Wikipedia maintenance</description>
    <icon href="commons-nuvola-web-broom.png"/>
    <shortcut>
      <desktop/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <!-- the micro-version request might be triggering the 
    Out-Of-Date Java version warning -->
    <j2se version="1.5+" java-vm-args="-Xmx512M"/>
    <jar href="WikipediaCleaner.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="org.wikipediacleaner.WikipediaCleaner"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links and analysis. I didn't know about JaNeLA, quite handy tool to clean up the jnlp file.


http://site4145.mutu.sivit.org/WikiCleaner/WikiCleaner.jnlp is still the JNLP for the installation with the self-signed jar, so it's normal to have the warning and not being able to trust the application once and for all.


http://site4145.mutu.sivit.org/WikiCleaner/WikiCleanerTest.jnlp is the test JNLP with the application signed with my certificate provided by Certum. If you want to try it, it should work correctly now.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, the following procedure worked for me. It is based on the answer by Eric David.

**Get your Certificate**

Go on the "Certum Certification" website in the "OpenSource Code Signing" section. Buy a certificate and follow the creation procedure.

**Get the Public Key for Code Signing**

Get the [Public Key of Certum Code Signing CA](https://www.certum.eu/certum/cert,expertise_root_certificates.xml#CCSCA), probably the CA SHA2 key [cscasha2.cer](https://repository.certum.pl/cscasha2.cer).

**Convert the certificate to pkcs12 format**

- Import your own certificate (the one you got from Certum) into Firefox: 
   menu item settings - advanced - certificates - show certificates.
- Import the CA SHA2 puplic key (used by Certum to sign your certificate): 
   tab cert. authorities - import.
- Verify. It should tell that it has been verified: 
   tab own certificates - show.
- Export the certificate: 
   tab own certificates - save - as pkcs12 (e.g. to  mycert.p12)

**Convert from pkcs12 format to jks format**

Find the alias used in your pkcs12 file. It will be similar to "*unizeto technologies s.a. id von open source developer, YOUR NAME*".

```
keytool -list -v -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mycert.p12 > out.txt
grep Aliasname out.txt
```

Then convert the pkcs12 file into java's jks format. This step could be omitted, but once done it is convenient.

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mycert.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias "ALIASNAME" -destkeystore mycert.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass PASSWORD -destalias SHORTALIAS
```

**Sign your jar file**

To avoid warnings to the webstart user, the jar manifest file should contain the following attributes:

- Application-Name: APPNAME
- Permissions: all-permissions
- Codebase: URL
- Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: URL

Sign your jar file using the following command:

```
jarsigner -keystore mycert.jks -tsa http://time.certum.pl FILENAME.jar SHORTALIAS
```

Comment: If Firefox does not export the certificate "Failed to create the PKCS #12 backup file for unknown reasons." use [pk12util](http://superuser.com/questions/586245/pull-certificate-from-firefox-without-using-firefox?newreg=f8b2ddb328ab495994735c9645aa7f97) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem on mine today with this :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Trusted-Library: true
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Trusted-Only: false
Application-Name: My app
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.6.0_16 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Codebase: *
```

Comment: Thanks, but no change at all: editor is still displayed as UNKNOWN and there's no way to accept the application once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21263769), to remove the UNKNOWN PUBLISHER warning you can add the certificate you used to sign the jar into the Signer Jar of the Java Control Panel: Configure Java -> Security -> Manage Certificates -> Signer Jar option -> Import.