# self signed JAR for JNLP

Tags: java, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

Our organization is having 15000+ computers some are connected in LAN and more of them are on VPN, we have developed an  java application which need to be run through JNLP. While working on JNLP I come to know that if JNLP file has `<all-permissions/>` under `<security>` tag then executing JAR must be signed.

I tried with self singing using `keytool` and `jarsigner` but when I tried to publish this through JNLP but on target machine java 7 showed message that `Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running` I know I can bypass this by doing security settings in `java control panel` but that's not practical solution for 15000+ computers.

I also checked,

[Signing a jar file with trusted certificate for JWS deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458676/signing-a-jar-file-with-trusted-certificate-for-jws-deployment) for "OpenSource Code Signing", but now its no more free. It costs €14.00 gross don't know for per year or for lifetime. Well it's still affordable so I added it in cart and while cart checkout my country i.e India is not listed in country dropdown list. So is there any workaround?