# How to populate Application and Publisher in the Java7u45 applet security dialog

Tags: java, security, applet, digital-signature, security-warning

I have a signed applet which I'm loading on my web page. When Java7u45 was released, this security dialog started to pop up:

[image: Java Security Dialog]

I read that I need to add certain attributes (Application-Name and Built-By) in the Manifest file of my JAR, but no matter what I add, the Application and Publisher fields are always UNKNOWN. Is there any way to get these values populated?

ANSWER: I accidentally found the reason why these fields were not populated. It seems that you have to have the Java Cache enabled in the Java preferences, in order for the Java to cache the applet information and display it to you the next time you try to load the applet. In my case, I've disabled the Java cache, but when I re-enabled it, the Application, and Publisher fields started to populate properly.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453089/signed-applet-doesnt-show-publisher-information ?

Comment: I'm using a certificate by thawte, so it's probably not the same issue. Also, I posted this question because this security dialog is different from any other security dialogs presented in earlier versions of Java, and so far I haven't came across an applet that has these values populated.